# Adding a column to a pandas dataframe based on cell values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is something I have:

```
list1_ = [("1","a","a1"),("1","b","b1"),("1","c","c"),("2","a","a2")]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(list1_,columns = ["user","col1","col2"])
list2_ = [("1","b","b2"),("1","a","a2"),("2","a","a3"),("1","c","c2")]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list2_,columns = ["user","col1","col3"])
```

What I am trying to do is is for (user,col1) in df2 match the pair with df1 and add col3 in df1... basically make df1: (user, col1,col2,col3) for the same cell values.
The end result should look like this:

```
list3_ = [("1","a","a1","a2"),("1","b","b1","b2"),("1","c","c","c2"), 
("2","a","a2","a3")]
df3 = pd.DataFrame(list3_,columns = ["user","col1","col2","col3"])
```

Please note: I read df1 from a csv file, and I create df2 using list2_. Therefore, I have some data in the form of list2_ but not in the form of list1_. So, would like to use only df1, list2_ and/or df2.

Comment: It seems need `merge`

Comment: I did try. seemed to raise errors:/

Comment: what error? that can be solved easier ;-)

Comment: You can check [merge 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101?noredirect=1&lq=1), but if some specific problem try explain more...

Comment: It works :') !!! I need to check it on a larger dataset though but I guess I get the idea now! Thanks a ton @nixon

Comment: You're welcome @AvantikaBanerjee :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`pd.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df1.merge(df2, on = ['user','col1'])

   user col1 col2 col3
0    1    a   a1   a2
1    1    b   b1   b2
2    1    c    c   c2
3    2    a   a2   a3
```

Comment: _Most_ questions involving `merge` (including this one) can now be hammered as duplicate of [Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101?noredirect=1&lq=1). Encouraging all users to do so, let's keep this tag clean :)

Comment: Thank you @coldspeed for the comment, but hadn't come across it earlier

Comment: No none of them are. And even though I would not agree on a solution you may give at some point I don't think I've ever downvoted you, as generally your solutions are both pretty fast and neat

Comment: @nixon - It is really bad... So somebody want I think you are downvoter :( It is really bad :(

Comment: well @jezrael good enough you now know that those are not mine :)